# How do I specify foreign_key and class when using has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How do I tell a `has_many :through` association which `foreign_key` and/or `class`to use?

I've tried every permutation of the above and usually receive: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'relation_delegate_class' for "User":String`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141031013511) do

 create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "creator_id"
  end

  create_table "messages_views", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "message_viewed"
    t.integer "message_viewer"
  end

  create_table "shows_viewers", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

---

```
class MessagesView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message_viewed
  belongs_to :message_viewer
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :messages_views
  has_many :message_viewers, through: :messages_views, class: 'User', foreign_key: 'message_viewer'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :messages_views
  has_many :message_vieweds, through: :messages_views, class: 'Message', foreign_key: 'message_viewed'
end
```

[This](https://github.com/ethagnawl/Associations-are-Hard) is the current state of the app.

Comment: Can you post the line of code where you're attempting to do this? For some reason you're invoking an active record relation on a String.

Comment: @PaulRichter I was running: `Message.last.message_viewers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem with the association table and your code should be like that :

```
class MessagesView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message_viewed, class_name: 'Message'
  belongs_to :message_viewer, class_name: 'User'
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :messages_views, foreign_key: 'message_viewed', class_name: "messages_view"
  has_many :message_viewers, through: :messages_views, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'message_viewer'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :messages_views, foreign_key: 'message_viewer', class_name: "messages_view"
  has_many :message_vieweds, through: :messages_views, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'message_viewed'
end
```

Comment: Ok, that changed the error message: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :message_views in model Message`

Comment: Model Message has messageS_views not message_views are you sure that you wrote messages plural not singular ?

Comment: Where are you referring to?

Comment: Model message does not have message_views association at all but it has messages_views and rails will automatically map it to the MessagesView model, to make sure add class_name: "messages_view" like in my answer above to make sure that it refers to the right model.

Comment: You were spot on. I renamed the join table `message_views` and the model `message_view` and everything worked as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is better to follow the conventions anyway. you are welcome.